# Why don't Bound Arrows show up when I use the Bound Bow spell?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was told in the past that when you cast the Bound Bow spell and have no arrows, the game spawns 100 Bound Arrows and equips them so you can actually use the bow. However, every time I've cast the spell (with or without arrows in my inventory) they never equip. I've seen them show up in my inventory via console and even equipped them with console but they don't do it on their own. And being bound weapons from a spell, they also don't show up in my inventory (well they do in the console window but not in the actual "player facing" inventory). Is there any way to fix this? Also why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: That's still how it is per [video](https://youtu.be/kNKkT4stgyc?t=25). It's suppose to auto-equip the arrows when casting the bound bow. Do you have any mods loaded?

Comment: @Nelson I'll upload a full mod list when I get the chance but it may be a few days

Comment: You don't need to post the mod list, since we can't do anything to fix conflicts to begin with. Try it vanilla and see if it is still an issue (create multiple saves and try loading it in vanilla). If it works then it is a mod issue (it usually is). Next will be to isolate which mod is causing the problems, and that's strictly trial and error on your part.

Comment: @Nelson if I do upload a mod list however there's a chance that someone might already know which mod(s) may be causing it. I"ll still try in vanilla though to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, this is directly driven by a script.  If you have mods installed, double check which ones are overwriting the BoundBowEnchEffect Script, or something named along those lines.  The script should have a line or two that controls how many bound arrows are added and equipped when the bow is summoned upon casting the spell, and there are some mods that tweak or overwrite this script to achieve different things.  If you have no mods installed, it still might be a good idea to refresh your scripts by extracting them again from Scripts.rar to confirm the scripts are all there and compiled correctly.  If you are using SSE, I am not sure how this process might be different, but this would be my first bit of troubleshooting in Skyrim LE.  I think the main difference with SSE and LE regarding scripts is the folder structure, so make sure you unpack the archive to the correct place for your installation.

Comment: Just re-read the OP and realized the script line in question would be the one for equipping the arrows.  I think that some script commands are called from other scripts, especially if you have SKSE installed for some mods.  There is a chance when modding Skyrim that the base scripts or their overwriting mod versions can become corrupted, so the fix I described is a good thing to rule out.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple, the bow uses its own arrows meaning, you can't use bound arrows for another bow but instead they are, lets say a 2 for one deal with the bow and can only be used with the conjured bow.